# How to plot user-defined function with multiple variables

Tags: plotting, functions

I wanted to plot the function:

```
TheoreticalT[n2_, k2_, w_] := (2*cn2[n2, k2]*(n1 + n3)*E^i(2*Pi*w*d2 (cn2[n2, k2] - 1))/c))/
          ((n1 + cn2[n2, k2])*(n3 + cn2[n2, k2]) - (cn2[n2, k2] - n1)*(cn2[n2, k2] - n3)*
          e^(i(2*cn2[n2, k2]*2*Pi*w*d2)/c));
```

with n2 and k2 defined from:

```
cn2[n2_, k2_] := n2 - ik2;
```

and all the other variables being constants (n1, n3, d2, c):

```
n1 = 1 + i0; (*complex index of refraction of air*)
n3 = 1.7862 + I 0; (*complex index of refraction of substrate*)
d2 = 2.9477*10^-5; (*thickness of the sample(mm)*)
c = 0.29979;(*speed of light:mm/ps*)
```

I have tried  doing a simple plot of just the n2 variable:

```
Plot[TheoreticalT[n2_, w_], {w, 0, 3}, Evaluated -> True]
```

But I'm not seeing any plot:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Any suggestions on how to proceed? Thank you
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9wXI.png

Comment: Please provide a complete minimal example of your problem.
There are variables n2, n3 etc that are undefined, are you setting them somewhere? If yes please provide them.

Comment: Hi, I edited it already. n1 and n3 are also constants

Comment: Please provide the whole *code* where you set all free variables.

Comment: I edited it again. Thank you

Comment: You mean to paste exactly from my Mathematica code? It looked different when I just directly copied it so I edited it. Here's the code directly pasted: ```TheoreticalT[n2_, k2_, 
   w_] := (2*cn2[n2, k2]*(n1 + n3)*E^(
     I (2 \[Pi] w  d2 (cn2[n2, k2] - 1))/
      c))/((n1 + cn2[n2, k2])*(n3 + cn2[n2, k2]) - (cn2[n2, k2] - 
        n1)*(cn2[n2, k2] - n3)*E^(I (2 cn2[n2, k2] 2 \[Pi] w d2 )/c));```

Comment: Try exactly this: `n1=1+i0;n3=1.7862+I0;d2=2.9477*10^-5;c=0.29979;
cn2[n2_,k2_]:=n2-ik2;
TheoreticalT[n2_,k2_,w_]:=(2*cn2[n2,k2]*(n1+n3)*E^i(2*Pi*w*d2(cn2[n2,k2]-1))/c))/
((n1+cn2[n2,k2])*(n3+cn2[n2,k2])-(cn2[n2,k2]-n1)*(cn2[n2,k2]-n3)*
e^(i(2*cn2[n2,k2]*2*Pi*w*d2)/c));
Table[TheoreticalT[n2,k2,w],{w,0,3}]` Missing `(` Change `i0` to `I 0` Change `I0` to `I 0`  Change `E^i` to `E^I` Change `e^(i` to `E^(I` Now <shift><Enter> to run.  See `ik2` and `n2` are not initialized. Fix that.with `ik2=3;n2=5;` Now add a line `Plot[ReIm[TheoreticalT[n2,k2,w]],{w,0,3}]` and the plot appears. Try it.

Comment: It works! Thank you. Could you explain why I needed to change these: ```i0``` to ```I 0``` Change ```I0``` to ```I 0``` Change ```E^i``` to ```E^I``` Change ```e^(i``` to ```E^(I``` ? Is it just with the syntax?

Comment: Mathematica is strict about capitalization. For input `Sqrt[-1]` is `I` and not `i` Any letter followed by letters or numbers is a variable. But `3y` is `3*y` because it does not start with a letter. It does not understand you may think i0 is the square root of -1 and then multiplied by zero. For input `E` is Euler's constant and not `e` When a plot will not appear think "complex numbers? or undefined variables?" Trying `Table` instead can sometimes show you what is the problem, but you must have the right step size to see the problem. I hope this helped..

Comment: I see. I'm still getting familiar with Mathematica's syntax so I didn't catch these. Thank you so much! Have a great week ahead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Reason is that you try to plot a function Mathematica does not know: `TheoreticalT` takes in 3 input values not two. Also the syntax is different, see below. Also you have not set all variables in your provided code the following parameters are free:

```
ik2, i0, e , i, n2
```

I think you want to change e->E and i->I.
Notice Mathematica Notebook shows unknown variables in blue.
You further want to change:

```
Plot[TheoreticalT[n2_, w_], {w, 0, 3}, Evaluated -> True]
```

into:

```
Plot[{Re@TheoreticalT[n2, k2, w], Im@TheoreticalT[n2, k2, w]}, {w, 0, 3}]
```

Which means you need to set k2 as well.

Comment: there is also a bracket missing in the exponent here:
`*(n1 + n3)*E^i(2*Pi*w*d2 (cn2[n2, k`

Comment: Wow thank you for answering. Let me try it out